# PowerMock Private method with null pointer exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

So I have code something like this

```
Class JobSearchService() {
    private SearchSetUpImpl searchSetUp;
    ...

    SearchIndex si = generateIndexes(id);
    Job jobs = si.readJobs(keyWord); // <-- si is null , null pointer         exception....
    ...
}

private Job generateIndexes(Id id) {
    ...
}
```

I wanted to use powerMock to return the jobs but it always return null for si.

In my test I have

```
PowerMockito.when(JSS, PowerMockito.method(JobSearchService.class,
    "generateIndexes", WorkId.class))
    .withArguments(id)
    .thenReturn(si);
```

How do I write the next procedure to skip or to return a proper Job without hitting null value?
I have also mocked si `SearchIndex si = Mockito.mock(SearchIndex.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap the SearchIndex into your own class.

```
class JobReader {

    Job readJobs(Id id, String keyWord) {
        SearchIndex si = generateIndexes(id);
        return si.readJobs(keyWord);
    }
}
```

and then you can mock the JobReader without PowerMock. Just inject it to wherever you need to use it.